# Source of the manpages on the current OS

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to get the source of the manpage on the system i will be using.
My problem is that i don t know what path they are (different depending the Unix/Linux flavor)

I know how to list the all the manpages by doing man -k . 
But i can't get the source !

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could look for MANPATH lines in /etc/man.config